# Error when renaming option

Tags: plugins, options

**UPDATE:** This error came from WP_DEBUG...of course, embedded_url didn't exist yet. However, when I set the value of $options[embedded_url] using the form, the $options array magically adds both the new value of embedded_url AND somehow remembers an old value of text_string. I've added

```
unset($options['text_string']);
```

to my code, but as soon as I press the Save Settings button, it's right back in the $options again. text_string does not exist anywhere in my code anymore. It's totally gone. Where is this text_string ghost?!

---

I followed [this tutorial](http://ottopress.com/2009/wordpress-settings-api-tutorial/) almost word for word to create a custom admin/settings page for a plugin I created. I tried to change the option name `text_string` to something else – `embedded_url`. I have WP_DEBUG enabled. When I loaded my plugin’s settings page, right above my text input field is this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: embedded_url in ….

and then it points to the echo line of this function:

```
function plugin_setting_url() {
$options = get_option('plugin_options');
echo "<input id='plugin_url' name='plugin_options[embedded_url]' size='40' type='text' value='{$options['embedded_url']}' />";
}
```

Since this is the only place that `text_string` appears in the tutorial other than the validation method, I do not understand why `embedded_url` is not defined in the same manner as `text_string` was. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: $plugin_options[embedded_url] - you're missing the $. and if it's an array... you better do name='" $plugin_options['embedded_url'] . "'

Comment: Thanks for the response, gdaniel - The tutorial does not use a $ in front of the name in their echo <input....>. Nonetheless, I did as you recommended and I am still receiving the same warning AND a new warning saying plugin_options is an undefined variable.

Comment: Then it was probably correct before. Sry. I thought that was a variable being passed by php, but it looks like it's just a regular array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to set a default value when you use get_option

function plugin_setting_url() {
$options = get_option('plugin_options', array('embedded_url'=>''));
echo "";
}

Unless plugin_options already exists, then you would need to use wp_parse_args to merge two arrays.

function plugin_setting_url() {
$options = wp_parse_args(get_option('plugin_options',array()),array('embedded_url'=>''));
echo "";
}

Comment: Thanks DaveDunn. I added the line you recommended. And my text_string ghost is also gone now that I ran a command to delete 'plugin_options'. Seems like I'm up and running again! Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I just had a look at the tutorial you linked to. I think the text_string hung around because the validation function plugin_options_validate uses get_option and then added your new index before saving.